# Retrieve all Accounts if a users has Read Access to them using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am at on-prem environment of Dynamics CRM 2011, I want to enlist all those accounts to whom a user have read access. So far, I am just reach out to the following but it is by just checking if the user have ReadAcces. But I want to query once and populate all those accounts the user have read access.

```
private static bool retrieveReadAccess(IOrganizationService service, Guid userId, Guid avcId)
    {
        //retrieve user ReadAccess to account
        RetrievePrincipalAccessRequest principalAccessReq = new RetrievePrincipalAccessRequest
        {
            Principal = new EntityReference("systemuser", userId),
            Target = new EntityReference("account", avcId)
        };
        RetrievePrincipalAccessResponse principalAccessRes = (RetrievePrincipalAccessResponse)service.Execute(principalAccessReq);

        if (principalAccessRes.AccessRights.HasFlag(AccessRights.ReadAccess))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of accounts that a certain user can read, use the CallerId parameter when you make a call to the SDK:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309629.aspx

This will execute the API call as if it came from that user and will only return records that the user is allowed to see.

```
// Retrieve the system user ID of the user to impersonate.
OrganizationServiceContext orgContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(_serviceProxy);
_userId = (from user in orgContext.CreateQuery<SystemUser>()
          where user.FullName == "Kevin Cook"
          select user.SystemUserId.Value).FirstOrDefault();

// To impersonate another user, set the OrganizationServiceProxy.CallerId
// property to the ID of the other user.
_serviceProxy.CallerId = _userId;

// Use serviceProxy for any API calls and it will run as the above user
```

Comment: Josh, thank you for your reply. Let me repeat my question in some other way.

I am the system administrator and I want to share the contact to those users only who have at least ReadAccess to the parent Account. So that is why instead of comparing account one by one with the User's guid I want to get all accounts a user can read in an array and then check parent account id if it falls in that array then share the child contact.

Does that make sense?